# How generate column using for loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to make this function produce column `occLvl_` loop 3 time and using `explode` to fetch each value from sql CONCAT. So the result will become like this.

```
[{
   "accommodationID": "LA56",
   "occLvl_0": "40.00",
   "occLvl_1": "70.00",
   "occLvl_2": "90.00"
}]
```

```php
function getOccLevel(){
  global $ehorsObj;
  $occArray = array();

  $sql = "SELECT accommodationID, GROUP_CONCAT(occLevelDesc) AS occLevels
          FROM tblSamAccOccLevels
          WHERE ACTIVE = 'y'
          GROUP BY accommodationID
          ORDER BY accommodationID ASC, occLevelDesc ASC "; 
  $GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sql, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
  while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){

    $occArray[] = array(
      'accommodationID' => $row['accommodationID'],
    );
    //seem the method below is not working
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
      $occArray["occLvl_".$j] = explode(",", $row['occLevels']) 
    }
  } 
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  $result = json_encode($occArray);
  echo $result; 
}
```

*Result of the query*

```
accommodationID         occLevels
     LA56           40.00, 70.00, 90.00
```

Comment: my mistake, already remove the `tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making numerically named object properties/variables (`occLvl_0` etc.) is generally a bad idea as it makes it difficult to work with them in any regular manner (e.g. using a loop). It is better practice to put the values into an array:

```
while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){
    $occArray[] = array(
        'accommodationID' => $row['accommodationID'],
        'occLvl' => explode(",", $row['occLevels'])
    );
}
```

This will give you an output JSON that looks something like:

```
[
    {
        "accommodationID": "LA56",
        "occLvl": [
            40,
            70,
            90
        ]
    },
    {
        "accommodationID": "PQ45",
        "occLvl": [
            30,
            60,
            100
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

And in your JS you can then iterate over the `occLvl` array to get the values.

If you need the data in the form you describe, then you need to iterate over the exploded `occLevels` value to generate the individual values, pushing them with the `accommodationID` into a new array and then pushing that array to `$occArray`:

```
while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){
    $this_occ = array(
            'accommodationID' => $row['accommodationID'],
        );
    foreach (explode(",", $row['occLevels']) as $key => $occLvl) {
        $this_occ["occLvl_$key"] = $occLvl;
    }
    $occArray[] = $this_occ;
}
```

Comment: the reason why I wanted to using loop because it need place into a loop table later on.

Comment: Well it's much easier to iterate over an array of values in a loop than it is to try and process a lot of different variable names

Comment: Im using [kendo platform](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-generate-model-from-data) and that is one of the reason I want it generate the loop column.

Answer (score 0):

Explode returns an array. You should explode before the loop and iterate through the result of that explode in the loop

Comment: Can you provide an example in code for the user to understand?